# warning 10 : this expression should have type unit

Tags: ocaml

I'm writing a program in ocaml containing some loops "for", my problem is that for each of these cycles you receive this message: "warning 10 : this expression should have type unit. "

Example :

```
    let f q p rho= 

       let x = [] in  
       if q > p then
          for i=0 to rho do
              x= q :: x
          done;    
    x;;
```

this every time I use a cycle "for" ,how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

The error is because the `for` does not return anything, and so the inside of the loop to be purely for side-effect. So it should have unit type. Your use of `=` does not have unit type, because `=` is in fact the equality operator, comparing two values, and returning `true` or `false`.

So you are using the wrong operator. It appears that you are trying to "assign" to `x`. But in ML, you cannot assign to "variables", because they are bound to a value when they are defined and cannot change. One way to get mutability, is to use a mutable cell (called a "reference"): you use the `ref` function to create the mutable cell from an initial value; the `!` operator to get its value out; and the `:=` operator to change the value inside.

So for example:

```
let f q p rho= 

   let x = ref [] in  
   if q > p then
      for i=0 to rho do
          x := q :: !x
      done;    
   !x;;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, thong your example adding "!" :  x := q :: !x

Answer (score 3):

This kind of loop is probably best expressed using recursion:

```
let f q p rho= 
  let rec loop i =
    if i > rho then
      []
    else
      q::(loop (i+1))
   in
   if q > p then
      loop 0
   else
      [];;
```

Or we can make it tail recursive:

```
let f q p rho= 
  let rec loop i acc =
    if i > rho then
      acc
    else
      loop (i+1) (q::acc)
   in
   if q > p then
      loop 0 []
   else
      [];;
```